# How to use filtering and stream copy together with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 8  -i  input.mp4  -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

can set codec. However, to filter:

```
ffmpeg  -i  input.mp4  -vf  crop=100:100:0:0 output.mp4
```

if combined:

```
Filtergraph 'crop=100:100:0:0' was defined for video output stream 0:0 but codec copy was selected.
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.
```

how to set codec like time clip?

Comment: you can't do that

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Not possible to copy & filter the same stream

Getting the error `Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together` means you have to avoid setting [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode (for example `-c:v copy`, `-c:a copy`, `-vcodec copy`, `-acodec copy`, `-c copy`, etc) when filtering the same video or audio.

Filtering requires the input video to be fully decoded into raw video, then the raw video is processed by the filter(s), finally it is encoded:

```
 _______              ______________
|       |            |              |
| input |  demuxer   | encoded data |   decoder
| file  | ---------> | packets      | -----+
|_______|            |______________|      |
                                           v
                                       _________
                                      |         |
                                      | decoded |
                                      | frames  |
                                      |_________|
                                           |
                                           v
                                       __________
                                      |          |
                                      | filtered |
                                      | frames   |
                                      |__________|
 ________             ______________       |
|        |           |              |      |
| output | <-------- | encoded data | <----+
| file   |   muxer   | packets      |   encoder
|________|           |______________|
```

[Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode omits decoding and encoding. It is like a copy and paste:

```
 _______              ______________            ________
|       |            |              |          |        |
| input |  demuxer   | encoded data |  muxer   | output |
| file  | ---------> | packets      | -------> | file   |
|_______|            |______________|          |________|
```

So **it is not possible to filter and stream copy the same stream at the same time**. However, you can stream copy unfiltered streams while filtering others. Example to filter video and stream copy audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw/2:-1[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output
```

See the [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Detailed-description) for more info.

Comment: I don't really understand the last example -- if I'm using the filter_complex setup, how do I do the copy of the audio/video? It sounds like your answer is basically saying "you can't do both streamcopy and filter_complex, but then it ends with 'oh here's how you do both streamcopy and filter_complex'.

Comment: For example, I have a script that generates a filter_complex graph to be able to concatenate all the videos in a directory.

Here's an example of the ffmpeg command it generates at the end:

 ffmpeg  -i /run/user/1000/gvfs/5f_source.mp4  -i /run/user/1000/gvfs/iq4_source.mp4  -i /run/user/1000/gvfs/c6_source.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=unsafe=1:n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" 
 combined_video_-656x1232.mkv


How exactly would I modify this command (what do I add or remove) so that it stream copies rather than re-encoding?

Comment: I think @llogan meant that if you intend to filter only a single stream (in their final example, `[0:v]`), any untouched streams can be copied. I.e., if you're applying filters or anything requiring decoding *a single stream* (as opposed to "*a single input file*") all the other streams can be copied.