# ffmpeg - How to convert a quad (4ch) file to two separate stereo (2ch) files?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

The file is a 4-channel OGG.

I am already able to grab all 4 into mono files, but it contains two sets of stereo files which is what I want.

The first two channels are the vocals, the latter two are the instrumental.
I would like to have two output files, Vocals.ogg and Instrumental.ogg

I am not very experienced in channel mapping, yet and I'm sure the answer to this is simple and will help expand my understanding of channel mapping via ffmpeg.

My attempts included
`ffmpeg -i 4CHFILE.ogg -acodec copy -map_channel 0.0.0 00.ogg -acodec copy -map_channel 0.0.1 01.ogg -acodec copy -map_channel 0.0.2 02.ogg -acodec copy -map_channel 0.0.3 03.ogg`, making 4 separate mono files, which I have to import and stereo pair in my DAW. I'd like to be able to play them on-the-go with them already stereo-paired.

To attempt to make the vocals track I tried
`ffmpeg -i 4CHFILE.ogg -filter_complex "[0:a][0:b]join=inputs=2[e]" -map "[e]" -acodec copy Vocals.ogg` but that didn't work and I'm not sure how to use the mapping properly to explain which channels I want to join. The previous code example that made mono includes -map_channel but I'm not sure how to map to left or right for the output file.

Any help would be appreciated and help further my experience with ffmpeg, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use `-acodec copy` and `-filer-complex` at the same time, because the audio needs to be decoded in order to split the channels therefore you cannot copy the audio codec, more information: [How to use filtering and stream copy together with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53518589/how-to-use-filtering-and-stream-copy-together-with-ffmpeg)

My solution decodes a 4-channel OGG file into 2x 2-channel WAVE files:

```
ffmpeg -i 4CHFILE.ogg -af "pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1" Vocals.wav -af "pan=stereo|c0=c2|c1=c3" Instrumental.wav
```

This example will map the first and second channels of the input to the first and second channels of the `Vocals.wav` output. The third and fourth channels of the input will get mapped to the first and second channels of the `Instrumental.wav` output.

I would highly recommend to keep those files in the WAVE format and not convert them lossy (again) to OGG.

Comment: Perfect! This worked and did exactly what I was after!